# Find a permutation and its signature

Tags: functions, permutations

Can you help me out with this?

$ \alpha = (125)(1378)(12546)(126) $ 
I need to find $\alpha^{77}$ and the signature of $ \alpha $.

The solution I came up with is to calculate $\alpha^{2},\alpha^{3}$ and so on untill I get the identity. But I think that this is not a solution(or at least there's an easier way) since I calculated up to $\alpha^{9}$ and still didn't get the identity.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok... so  I'm not sure if I get it. If I write $\alpha$ as a product of disjoint cycles then $\alpha$ would be $\alpha = (2378)(465)$ which implies that $\alpha^{77} = (2378)^{77} (465)^{77}$.

Comment: Yes, and what is the power of a cycle like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by rewriting $\alpha$ as a single permutation instead of a product of permutations:

$\alpha = (125)(1378)(12546)(126) = \begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\
1&3&7&6&4&5&8&2\end{pmatrix}$

This was accomplished by following where each element gets mapped by the individual cycles (remember that cycles are applied from right to left):

$1\xrightarrow{(126)}2\xrightarrow{(12546)}5\xrightarrow{(1378)}5\xrightarrow{(125)}1$

With this new way of looking at $\alpha$, we can then write $\alpha$ as a product of disjoint cycles:

$\alpha = (1)(2378)(465)=(2378)(465)$

This was accomplished by following the path that each element takes via repeated applications of the permutation:

$2\mapsto 3\mapsto 7\mapsto 8\mapsto 2$, so one of the cycles is $(2378)$

Using this format, we can continue the problem with ease.  The signature of a permutation is related to the number of even length cycles in its disjoint cyclic representation.  Specifically, it is $(-1)^{\#\text{of even cycles in disjoint cycle representation}}$

> So, $\text{sgn}(\alpha)=-1$

Raising this to a larger power becomes easier as well since disjoint cycles commute.  We also know how powers act on a cycle.  $\sigma^{\text{length of}~\sigma} = e$.  We see that $\alpha^{12}=e$ (as $12=\text{lcm}(4,3)$).

$\alpha^{77}$ will be simplified as:

> $(2378)^{77}(465)^{77} = (2378)^{77\pmod{4}}(465)^{77\pmod{3}}=(2378)(465)^2=(2378)(456) = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\1&3&7&5&6&4&8&2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Anyway I have to start learning some more abstract algebra.